# Google Drive API upload file to the currently authenticated user on browser

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, playframework, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Here is the method I wrote in Java:

```
  public static String uploadToDrive(String directoryPath) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

    // Create a new file.
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName("My Spreadsheet");
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(directoryPath);
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", filePath);
    File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
            .setFields("id")
            .execute();

    // Share the file with the authorized user.
    
    String userEmail = service.about().get().setFields("user(emailAddress)").execute().getUser().getEmailAddress();


    Permission userPermission = new Permission()
            .setType("anyone")
            .setRole("reader");
    
    service.permissions().create(file.getId(), userPermission).execute();

    return "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + file.getId();
}
```

I want the file in the given path to be uploaded to Google Drive. The problem is that the file is uploaded to the account of the user in the credentials file. I want the file to be uploaded to the drive of the user authenticated in that browser session. How can I achieve this?